# How to send ATR to card

Tags: c++, smartcard

I have some card, wanted to get ATR from it (using method from some SDK).
Implementation looks like this:

```
unsigned char ATR[128]={0};
int len=33;
int maxlen=33;
ret = sd7816_ATR(0,1,ATR,len,maxlen,1);
```

first, second and last parameters to `sd7816_ATR` function should be like that.
The length fields I tried changing to different values, including 0 but no help.

My concern is the ATR string I am sending is *empty in the beginning,* and I am expecting
something to get written in it after the call finishes (which actually returns success).

But after call ATR is still empty .. What can be going wrong here?

**(I want to find out if card is of ISO/IEC 14443 or ISO/IEC 7816  type).**

Comment: Does the return value `ret` show you anything? Maybe the function didn't succeed for some reason...

Comment: @aardvarkk: yes like I said it returns success

Comment: Sorry, didn't read carefully enough evidently.

Comment: If this is a 14443 type B card then there is no ATS (which is normally translated into an ATR)

Comment: @owlstead: That's actually my problem: I don't know exactly what type of card this is?

Comment: Normally a reader is only of a specific type; even those with dual reader capability are seen as two devices. ISO/IEC 7816-1 to 3 is contact, ISO/IEC 14443 is contactless. So you may not need the ATR.

Comment: @owlstead: So you say ISO/IEC 7816 cards are Always contact? Like I said using this I wanted to determine type of card. Also note what I find weird is that the function for ATR itself has 7816 embedded in the name `sd7816_ATR`, so if this 14443 type card, this method should probably not work right?

Comment: 7816 consists of multiple parts. Only part 1-3 are specific to contact cards. The ATR is part of - eh - one of the contact card parts, probably part 3. So by definition an ATR does not apply to 14443. However, for type A cards, the ATS is often translated into an ATR. Welcome to the wondrous world of card reader software :)

Comment: @owlstead: ok(it is a bit confusing but ok). I wanted to send APDU commands to card, and the SDK is layered such that you will see separate functions for 7816 card (like `sd7816_ATR`) and separate functions for 14443 card. So probably it is good idea I better find out in the first place which type this card is right?

Comment: Yes, but again, you may just conclude that a card if of a specific type simply by looking at the reader. I mean, good luck getting a contact card working in a contactless reader. Nowhere to put the chip in :)

Comment: @owlstead: aah I see :) Ok, I think it supports both (reader looks like chip). The specification about features says: "Contact Card: ISO 7816 1/2/3, ClassB,C (3V,1.8V), T=0 and T=1". And about contactless it says: "ISO14443A 4(part 1-4), Mifare,
 Mifare Plus, DESFire EV1, ISO14443B, Felica"

Comment: Check your OS, does it show up as one or two readers in the device manager (if Windows) ?

Comment: @owlstead: I think it shows up as one. (ps. This is some excerpt from description too: "as well ISO18092 Near Field Communication (NFC) with build-in ISO7816 (T=0 T=1) SAM for advanced security.")

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51436/discussion-between-owlstead-and-dmcr-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to receive an ATR for a command specific for a ISO/IEC 7816-3 contact card. In this particular case, that's requested from a (SIM form) SAM card reader. However, you are trying to read out the contactless based reader.

Now contactless cards do not have an ATR. Some cards do have an ATS (i.e. ISO/IEC 14443 Type A cards), but that should be requested by a similar 14443 SELECT command. Some cards, particularly Type B cards, contain an EF.ATR to make up for the lack of (space within the) ATR. Still, an ATR/ATS has only limited functionality for identifying cards.

ISO/IEC 7816 is comprised of several parts: parts 1 to 3 describe contact cards and 4 and higher describe the Application level APDU commands and file structure of processor cards. If your contactless card implements ISO/IEC 7816-4 then you can - in general - also directly use the PCSC interface to send and receive APDU's to/from the card.

In general readers are for contact or contactless only. If you have a reader which contains both contact and contactless operation then in general they will show up as two different readers in the operating system. So in general, if you know the reader, you know if the card is a contact card or contactless card.

SAM slots may not be identified as readers by the operating system - you may only be able to access them using a low level interface. They are mainly used as a secure storage of keys from the terminal/inspection system/interface device or whatever the name is of the system that reads out the card.

Comment: Basically everything we discussed in the comments put together in a few paragraphs...

Comment: ah sure, thanks. Like I said in my imagination I was thinking to use above code to determine in the first place if I had 7816 type or 14443 type card. But now I think I have 144443 card, because I managed to send some apdu to it and get response

Comment: Actually, you have kind of both :) You've got a contactless 14443  card (T=CL) that is able to handle ISO 7816-4 (as that defines APDU's). What you don't have is a ISO 7816-3 contact (T=0 or T=1) card. It's better to think of ISO 7816-X as all separate standards, otherwise confusion *will* arise. This is true for many ISO/IEC standards by the way.